# Commas using SAS and TD SQL

Tags: sql, sas, teradata, number-formatting

I am using SAS to pull data in a Teradata environment. I am counting the rows in the Teradata table, but want the output to be in a comma format (i.e. 1,000,000). I was able to use the code below to display the value as a comma, but when I try to add the column in SAS, I can't since the output is in a character format. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to format the number value as comma, so that it can be used for calculation purposes in SAS? Thanks.

```
CAST(Count(*) as (format 'Z,ZZZ,ZZ9')) as char(10)) as rowCount,
```

Comment: Pull it as numeric and then format it on the SAS side as comma.

Comment: Do you want the value as a number or a string?  If you want it as a number why did you convert it to a string on the Teradata side?  That means you would have to convert back to a number on the SAS side if you want to do any arithmetic with it.  Watch out for "BIGINT" data types in Teradata, they don't translate well into SAS numeric variables.  You might want to cast it as FLOAT instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using pass through, pull it in as numeric and format it on the SAS side. You've now converted it to character (char10) and SAS doesn't do math on character variables which makes logical sense.

```
select rowCount format=comma12. from con
 (select 
      count(*) as rowCount ....
 )
```

If you have a `select *` you can always format it later in a data step or via PROC DATASETS. SAS separates the display and storage layers so the format controls the appearance but the underlying data still remains numeric.